# How can I get the content inside Ace (code editor) after clicking a button?

Tags: express, handlebars.js, ace-editor

I have a page with an embedded Ace code editor that will contain Java code. I want to get its contents via a POST request after a button is pressed.

I'm aware that one can do this in order to get the value:

```
var code = editor.getValue();
```

However, I'm not too sure how I would get this value from my route handler. Ideally, I'd like to have the editor script inside a separate .js file, but I can't seem to get it to be recognized by anything.

In my handlebars template for /myroute/*

```
<div class = "bigclass">

    some divs 

    <div id = "containerclass">
        <div id = "editor"></div>
        <script src = "https://pagecdn.io/lib/ace/1.4.8/ace.js", type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8"></script>
        <script>
            var editor = ace.edit("editor");
            editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
            editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/java");
            editor.session.setUseWrapMode(true);
            editor.setValue("Hello"); 
            editor.clearSelection();
        </script>
    </div>

    some more divs 

    <div id = "someotherclass"> 
        <form method = "POST" action = ""> 
            <button style = "text-align: center" type="submit" class="btn"> Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Route Handler for /myroute/*

```
app.post('/myroute/*', function(req, res) {
    // Get the contents of the editor 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to set an input inside your form, and fill it every time a change is done on the editor.

On clicking submit, you can have the value from the `req.body`

```
<div class = "bigclass">

    some divs 

    <div id = "containerclass">
        <div id = "editor"></div>
        <script src = "https://pagecdn.io/lib/ace/1.4.8/ace.js", type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8"></script>

    </div>

    some more divs 

    <div id = "someotherclass"> 
        <form method = "POST" action = ""> 
            <textarea name="content" id="content"></textarea>
            <button style = "text-align: center" type="submit" class="btn"> Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

        <script>
            var editor = ace.edit("editor");
            editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
            editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/java");
            editor.session.setUseWrapMode(true);
           editor.getSession().on("change", function () {                
                document.getElementById('content').val(editor.getSession().getValue());
           });
            editor.setValue("Hello"); 
            editor.clearSelection();
        </script>
```

Server:

```
app.post('/myroute/*', function(req, res) {
    const content = req.body.content; 
});
```